# How to open a jsp page in new window of browser

Tags: jsp, jakarta-ee

I have a anchor tag link in my current jsp page  ,clicking on which studentid is passed as query string and I want to open a new window of browser in which details of student will be displayed.
I am using simple jsp and servlet.
How to do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<a href="javaScript:{openNewWindow();}"></a>

   function openNewWindow()
    {
    window.open("jsp name")
    }
```

Comment: @Vini if you got the solution with my answer please make this as answer

Answer (score 0):

how about using javascript

```
window.open('your')
```

Comment: Why don't you post a bit more details on how to implement this using javascript instead of an oneliner ?

Answer (score 0):

Add target in your hyperlink.

```
<a href="jsp page name" target = "_blank">Click here</a>
```

This will open in new tab when we click on it.